# How to describe a person who loves a very cold environment (below 20°C/68°F)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or two words that describes a person who loves to be in a very cold environment (for example, below 20°C or 68°F) and dislikes temperatures that are not very cold?

Comment: Canadian ?      ...........

Comment: Wait ...how is 20C considered *very* cold? Are you thermophilic or something?

Comment: @JeffSahol, sorry, I am a Hyperthermophilic ... just kidding.

Comment: *Moi.* . . . . .

Comment: Since 20C = 68F, I think the word you're looking for is 'normal' :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Cryophilic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cryophilic) is the only word that comes to my mind:

> Having an affinity for or thriving at low temperatures.

The antonym is *thermophilic*.

Comment: This is the general term. Is there one including the specific 20C limit?

Comment: @Hugo: Why would there be? What's so special about 20C? Am I to understand that there should be a special word for every temperature limit? :)

Comment: I've no idea why there would be, but that's what the question's asking...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I had another word after searching for a while - the word is - **Psychrophiles**

(Just in case any one want other alternative)

Comment: Psychrophile was the word we used in microbiology to describe bacteria that prefer or survive in refrigerator temperatures. Psychrophiles are extremophilic bacteria or archaea which are cold‐loving, having an optimal temperature for growth at about 15°C or lower, a maximal temperature for growth at about 20°C and a minimal temperature for growth at 0°C or lower. If you ever wondered why your vegetables seem to go bad after about a week or two, thank the psychrophiles. They can't spoil your vegetables as quickly in the refrigerator, but they do eventually get around to it. I myself am a psychro